# Good examples or documentation of XIFF implementation?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, xmpp, xiff

[XIFF](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/xiff/) is an implemenation of the [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabber) protocol in actionscript.

So far, all the examples and documentation I have seen are sparse. Does anyone know a good explanation of the most recent version of XIFF and/or good examples of working Flex/AIR applications?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there are not a ton of good examples / docs online.

Check out:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/index.php?s=xiff

for a couple of examples that show how to get started.

mike

Comment: the link seems to be outdated. Getting a 403.